# Is it idiomatic to say "are you faking eating something?"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [fake](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fake_3)
>
> 1 [transitive] fake something to make something false appear to be real, especially in order to cheat somebody
>
> She faked her mother's signature on the document.
>
> He arranged the accident in order to fake his own death.
>
> 2[transitive, intransitive] **fake (something)** to pretend to
>   have a particular feeling, illness, etc.
>
> She's not really sick—she's just faking it.
>
> He faked a yawn.

Your child is pretending to eat something.

Is it idiomatic to say "**are you faking eating something?**" because your child may not understand the formal verb "**pretend**" ?

Comment: I wouldn't say that _pretend_ was formal. In my experience it's the usual word used of, and by, children when playing imaginative games - 'Let's pretend we're pirates' and so on.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. The ***specific*** phrase *are faking eating something* is an unusual construction. (It would be more natural as *are you faking **the** eating of something*.) But *are you pretending eating something* is even more unnatural. However, the *reason* they're unusual (or wrong) is not because of the specific verb, but because of the construction used. In short, if you want to focus on **fake** versus **pretend**, you should use a phrase that focuses only on those specific words, and which doesn't have unusual syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is, here are a few usage instances:

From: [Apache Lance, Franciscan Cross](https://books.google.it/books?id=ty9uB09HnzgC&q=%22fake%20eating%22&dq=%22fake%20eating%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2yr2S89rpAhUCwMQBHeAIAQA4ChDoATAHegQIARAu://) by 
Florence Byham Weinberg

> ***It was easy enough to fake eating*** when the only light was that of the ceremonial fire

From [Performing Chekhov](https://books.google.it/books?id=zhuEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA118&dq=%22fake%20eating%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-k7Tq7trpAhVONOwKHZ2dAPIQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22fake%20eating%22&f=false)
By David Allen

> There's a big difference ***between fake eating and really eating,***  and I've never seen anyone fake eating convincingly.

From 
[Saying 'Yes!' to the Boss: Having Her Boss's Baby / Business or Pleasure ..](https://books.google.it/books?id=1mePSUHI1iQC&pg=PT25&dq=%22fake%20eating%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-k7Tq7trpAhVONOwKHZ2dAPIQ6AEIRTAE#v=onepage&q=%22fake%20eating%22&f=false)
By Susan Mallery, Julie Hogan, Shirley Rogers

> She couldn't imagine ever eating again, what with the nerves dancing around in her stomach, ***but she could probably fake eating if she had to.***

From: [Screen acting: how to succeed in motion pictures and television,](https://books.google.it/books?id=MHVZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22fake%20eating%22&dq=%22fake%20eating%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7kuXa8NrpAhXlpIsKHe-9Bgk4ChDoATADegQIARAV) by Brian Adams

> Should you be told to 'save the food' during rehearsal of an eating scene, ***fake eating until the scene is actually shot.***

Comment: So, actors fake eating, don't they?

Comment: Yes, I guess they do.

Answer (score 1):

Since definition #2 that you quoted does mean "to pretend" then using "fake" to mean "to pretend" would **not** be idiomatic. You are stating exactly what you mean.

> "Are you faking (something)?" = "Are you pretending (to do something)?"